# Undetected-Chromedriver Close Chrome Automatically After Few Seconds

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using:
Python 3.9
Chrome 93.0.4577.63
ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.15
Undetected-Chromedriver 3.0.3
Windows 10

I use the most simple code to open Chrome:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

driver = uc.Chrome ()
with driver:
     driver.get ('https://www.google.com/')
```

When Chrome is opened, in the up-right corner there is a message of Error, when I click on it says, New Extension Added, (Another program on your computer has added an extension that can change how Chrome works)
After a few seconds Chrome is closed automatically

Anybody know that cause it and what it's the solution?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is's simple your code just end after get google.com 
Add sleep or cycle with key for interupt. 
For example:

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import os

driver = uc.Chrome ()
with driver:
    driver.get ('https://www.google.com/')

os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31767988)